# Sprite-Kit: change the contact points color

Tags: merge, sprite-kit, nodes, contacts, points

- The scene background color is white.
- In the scene there are two sprite nodes (`SKSpriteNode`) *sprite 1* and *sprite 2* with black borders and transparent backgrounds.
- *sprite 2* moves.
- *sprite 2* reaches *sprite 1* and contacts it.

What I'm trying to do is **merging** the two **sprite contact borders** when they contact each other. With other words: I want to change the color of the contact points of both sprites into the scene background color. I tried to do this with the `blendMode` property. But it seems that the `blendMode` property works only with a node and his parent.

Does the `blendMode` property work only with a node and his parent? If yes, is there any way to change the colors of the contact points of two "normal sprite nodes"?

Thanks for any ideas.

**EDIT:**

- the background color is white.
- each sprite is transparent and has a border with black color.
- when a sprite **contacts** OR **is moving** along the border of another sprite, the black color of all contact points of both sprite borders changes to white (that is the background color). The color of all other border points of both sprites stays black.
- I put another picture with more details.

Thanks in advance.

[image: merge sprite borders]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blend mode will only blend textures together,  it will not remove that black border unless you are applying something like Xor Blending.  The actual sprite would blend to the destinations frame buffer, not the parent, so whatever is below the sprite at the time of rendering it.

> Blending the Sprite into the Framebuffer
>   The final stage of rendering is to blend the sprite’s texture into its destination framebuffer. The default behavior uses the alpha values of the texture to blend the texture with the destination pixels. However, you can use other blend modes when you want to add other special effects to a scene.
>
> You control the sprite’s blending behavior using the blendMode property. For example, an additive blend mode is useful to combine multiple sprites together, such as for fire or lighting. Listing 2-6 shows how to change the blend mode to use an additive blend.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Sprites/Sprites.html

To achieve what you are looking for, I wouldn't even mess with blending, instead have your sprite broken up into 2 sub sprites, the border, and the inside color.

What I mean by this is lets say you have a circle with radius 10 and a 1 pixel thick.  We create a node, that has a child that is just the border with a transparent area at radius 10, and another child that has a radius of 9, which will be filled with white.

Set the borders zposition to 0
Set the inside sprites zposition to 10.

When 2 sprites merge together, here is how drawing will be rendered

Sprite 1 border
Sprite 2 border
Sprite 1 inside
Sprite 2 inside

This will give you the effect you are looking for with the sprites merged together.

Of course, if your inside has transparent and not a solid color then we have a 
problem.  (Right now you are saying your BG is white, so we do not need transarency, your circle cam be white, but if you want to put a texture on the BG, then we have an issue.)

If you indeed want to keep your circle "transparent", then what you need to do is capture the background underneath before the border gets drawn, and make that the texture of your inner circles

Comment: @KnightOfDragon thank you for your answer. I have edited my question.

Comment: with your changes, you still want XOR blending,  but of course, you need to be careful because the 2 sprites need to blend on an empty background, then you need to turn off the XOR and add the background.  Your best  best is to create a new graphics context, draw your sprites with XOR blending in this, then create a texture out of this, make a new sprite that is both the merged sprites and overlay it on top with userinteractionEnabled set to false

Comment: Thanks @KnightOfDragon. If I understand you correctly, with creating a texture and making a new sprite that is both the merged sprites, I have only one sprite at the end. Right? But how can I then handle (touching, moving, position, etc.) with the sprites separately? I need to move, calcuate, etc. each sprite separately. Therefore I can't merge the sprites into one sprite. I need to merge only the contact poins of both borders, so that all other things stay separately. Thank you.

Comment: No you keep the old sprites and you place the new one on top, so it looks like its the same sprite but in reality it isnt.  Then when the sprites no longer merge, you remove the overlay

Comment: Ok. I hope that I understand you correctly. In this case, the new merged sprite that contains the two old sprites is on top and covers the two old sprites. That means that the old sprites are "blocked" from touching by the merged sprite. Correct? How can I touch one of the covert sprites and move it? Thank you.

Comment: You set `userInteractionEnabled = false` on the mergedsprite

Comment: Aha. Ok. I'll try that. Thanks. Is there any other way to merge the borders without using the graphics context and drawing a new merged sprite etc.? Maybe calculating all contact points and changing its color? Or any other way? Thank you.

Comment: If your sprite is just a hexagon, then you can have a sprite with 2 sub sprites underneath, one for the border, and one for the body, then render every possible border hole, and apply that on top

Comment: poking at it pixel by pixel will end up costing you in the long run, so you want to avoid that

Comment: If it is black and white with no scaling of your sprites, you actually could just make a sprite that is white, and scale it over the border

Comment: My sprites are not just a hexagon. I have many sprites with various forms / different figures. There are also Objects like flower, bottle, cup, ... But they all are simple and black and white. Thank you.

Comment: if it complex shapes like that, then yes, you may want to go the XOR approach,  good luck with your game

Comment: Thank you. I'll try that and see. Please wait a bit for accepting your answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have been thinking about this over and over,  what will work, is your sprite contains 2 sprites,  a border, and an inside.  Set your border z positions to zero,  set your sprites z positions to 10 (to be safe),  when your sprites draw, it will draw border and border, then inside and inside, giving you a merged look without any heavy math

Comment: Unfortunately I can award my bounty in 13 hours. Sorry for that!

Comment: Lol its fine i didnt answer it for the bounty i enjoy just helping. Keeps my mind fresh

Comment: If you end up doing a texture background approach let me know and ill explain how to do that,  you can do some cool effects like create a bubble look with it

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :)